# How to display selected sql data value to an overlay popup window

Tags: php, sql, popup, modal-dialog, overlay

I am a fresh newbie in web-database design. While I am creating a website also at the same time I study it and learn from it. But right now I am in need of your help.
Below is the exact working code. Can someone help me code it....

My Problem is this:
All records from database is shown in paginated view where `$row["name"]` is highlighted for the clickable overlay popup window.

Whereas my PROBLEM is?

- When this is clicked `<span class="page_name"><a class="show-popup" href="#">'.$row["name"].'</a> </span>` I need to use the `$row["id"]` primary key to locate the selected product in the database and then
- DISPLAY it in the overlay popup window under `DIV CLASS="OVERLAY-CONTENT"`.

---

```
<?php
session_start();
$catphp = $_SESSION['catphp'];
include("sqllnk.php"); //SQL connection
?>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="overlay/custom.js"></script>
<link href='overlay/overlaypopup.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<?php
//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
//validate page number is really numaric
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){ die('Invalid page number!'); }
//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);
//Limit our results within a specified range. 
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE itemcon='$catphp' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
//output results from database to a paginated window
echo '<ul class="page_result">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
// All records from database is shown in paginated view where $row["name"] is highlighted for the clickable overlay popup window. Whereas my PROBLEM is? When $row["name"] is clicked I need to use the $row["id"] primary key to locate the selected product in the database and then DISPLAY it in the overlay popup window under DIV CLASS="OVERLAY-CONTENT".
echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'.
<span class="product-thumb"><img src="uploads/thumbs/'.$row['pic'].'"></span>
<span class="page_name"><a class="show-popup" href="#">'.$row["name"].'</a> </span><br /><br />
<span class="page_description">'.$row["description"].'</span><br /><br />
<span class="page_price">Price:'.$row["price"].'</span>
</li>';
} ?>

<div class="overlay-bg">
<div class="overlay-content">
<p>Still working on details. <br /> Please come back soon.</p>
<?php // Here it should show the prefetch record in the database table ?>
<button class="close-btn">Close</button>
</div>
</div>

<?php
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

---

Here is the custom.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // show popup when you click on the link
    $('.show-popup').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
        var docHeight = $(document).height(); //grab the height of the page
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //grab the px value from the top of the page to where you're scrolling
        $('.overlay-bg').show().css({'height' : docHeight}); //display your popup and set height to the page height
        $('.overlay-content').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'}); //set the content 20px from the window top
      $
    });

    // hide popup when user clicks on close button
    $('.close-btn').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-bg').hide(); // hide the overlay
    });

    // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
    $('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-bg').hide();
    })
    // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
    $('.overlay-content').click(function(){
        return false;
    });

});
```

Can anyone please help me on this.... Thank you.

Comment: there are two ways to go about it. 1- load all the records and give popups id or class of the record id and then just show it on link click 2- load the record with that id in popup through ajax

Comment: will try to code that

Answer (score 0):

This question is mostly related to javascript. And to be more specific Ajax (a way to call asynchronously the web server to get some results).

Check fancybox ajax example: http://fancybox.net/  . It's exactly what you need.

You also need an URL(page) receiving as parameter (example: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php ) the ID of the database ROW, where you will display all the details for that specific row. What does ajax do? He goes to that URL in an asnyc manner (without disrupting your page) and fetches you the HTML of the result and then you (or fancybox) place it in a pop-up.

JQuery framework Ajax example: http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax

Also, I would like to suggest you to separate the PhP code from the HTML part. It will be much easyer to reuse code, or to read and understand code (I am talking mostly about the part of PHP where you call the database).

Check this tutorial for MVC Pattern in PhP: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Comment: Hi, the ajax used is for the pagination of the listed tables from the 1st php file.

Comment: It is this, <div id="results"></div>< ?php echo $pagination; ?>

Comment: For url page receiving parameter, actually i am already using it with a different value. it gets the category name of that needs to be filtered in the database table. that would be the $result from the query with value itemcon = $catphp

Comment: In order to get asynchronously the $row based on $id you need to create another page which will receive as parameter the $id and call it using ajax, then use jQuery(".overlay-content").html(result) to have it where you wanted.

Comment: I am still bit short in coding but i will try to put it together your suggesion, Miki.